# Change css to make black

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have fileupload control on my page and I have wrapped it around with fake button.Now I want to change the color of button to black.I tried various way but could not achieve. Here is my button and css:

```css
.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Browse</span>
    <input type="file" name="File" id="fileUpload" class="upload" style="background-color: black" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For it to work, you have to put **`style="background-color: black"`** to **`div.fileUpload`** instead of **`input#fileUpload`**.

**Code:**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" style="background-color: black">
        <span>Browse</span>
        <input type="file" name="File" id="fileUpload" class="upload"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" style="background-color: black;border:0;">
    <span>Browse</span>
    <input type="file" name="File" id="fileUpload" class="upload" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, you need a few minutes before you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap buttons has gradient `background-image: linear-gradient...` because for changes bg color u must set `background-image: none` and add tag name 
to get a higher priority than bootstrap styles, than add `background-color`, sorry for my bad english.

```css
div.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: none;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<!-- Свіжа збірка мінімізованих CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Додаткові теми -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Browse</span>
    <input type="file" name="File" id="fileUpload" class="upload"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using Bootstrap buttons (`btn btn-primary`), in order to change the button background color or hover color. You can right click the button then go to inspect element in your browser. Look in the inspector you will realize bootstrap has some classes that style the button as follows:

Overwrite this in your custom css to style the Bootstrap Button Background Colour

```
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
}
```

Overwrite this class to style the Bootstrap Hover Button Attributes

```
.btn:hover, .btn:focus, .btn.focus {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```